# Why my view can not recognize the UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

When I tag the image, there is no things to show? Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: add delegate to UIPanGestureRecognizer and target should be self not self.view1

Comment: please please post code instead of images.

Comment: please post what u have written for better answer. As beginner it is common:)

Comment: add [self.view add gestureRecognizer:urGestureRecognizer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _view2 = [[V0 alloc ]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    CGRect a = self.view2.frame;
    a.origin.x = 100;
    a.origin.y = 150;
    _view2.frame = a;
    _view2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.view2 addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self.view2 action:@selector(Up:)]];
```

i add the initWithFrame ,then my view can recognize my gesture

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `userInteractionEnabled` property is set to `NO` in `UIImageView` class. Maybe that is your problem.

[From UIImageView Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1621063-userinteractionenabled?language=objc)

> This property is inherited from the UIView parent class. This class changes the default value of this property to NO.

Checked with this fragment code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognized:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}

- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"It Works!");
}
```

Comment: I create the imageView by Main.storybord, and let the userInteractionEnabled equal yes, and i try this way ,it does not effective.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code its worked fine:

```
-(void)initialization
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)] autorelease];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 }
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = imageview;

    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
        CGPoint translatedCenter = CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y);
        CGPoint center = [self centerWithBounds:translatedCenter andViewFrame:[piece frame] andBoundingFrame:[[piece superview] frame]];
        [piece setCenter:center];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    }
}
```

Comment: where should  i  add the initialization?      do i have to delete the code in viewDidLoad?

Comment: you have to call this initialization method in viewdidload [self initialization];